# NSPredicate not finding records that exist in CoreData store using MagicalRecord

Tags: core-data

I am trying to check to see if appointments overlap in my iPad app; so I'm checking the *new* appointment's end time to *any* stored appointment's start time.  Once I get that working, I'll add another constraint, that of service tech.  This is the code I'm using in my predicate so far:

```
NSPredicate *nsp = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%@ > aStartTime",stopTime];
[apptDataArray addObjectsFromArray:[AppointmentInfo MR_findAllWithPredicate: nsp]];
```

There is a NSLog between the two statements above, which gives me this:

```
predicate: CAST(413323200.000000, "NSDate") > aStartTime
stopTime: 2014-02-05 20:00:00 +0000
serviceTech: Kellie
```

i know for a fact that there are stored appointments that satisfy the predicate, but it's not finding any of them.  What could be the cause of this, and how do I fix it?

Comment: This question doesn't have any dependencies on MagicalRecord. I suggest looking at your property names to see if they match. Also look at using >= to see if that finds data.

Comment: Hi Saul... I just put MR in the tags to cover all of my bases... sorry...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your predicate is malformed.  A predicate, at the simplest level, is $ATTRIBUTED compared against $VALUE.  You are at best reversing that which you really should not do.

What is `aStartTime`?

What kind of object is `stopTime`?

What does the entity `AppointmentInfo` look like?

Comment: Yes, the whole statement was malformed... corrected it and it works like a champ now...